# Placing the filepath of a file in the clipboard with a shortcut in Windows explorer

Tags: windows

I am looking for a Microsoft Windows program or user script that can place the filepath of a file in the clipboard with a shortcut when the file is selected in Windows explorer.

Any price or license  is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At customer sites (where I'm "forced" to use Windows), I use **[StExBar](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/StExBar.html)** for things like that:

- integrates with Explorer as toolbar
- offers buttons to copy the file name or its path to your clipboard (alternatively: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> as hotkey for this)
- similar for a "command window here" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>), running a command directly in the current directory ("command box") or creating a new directory (which I've mapped to <kbd>F7</kbd> – yeah, the good old Norton-Commander shortcut ;)
- several more features you didn't ask for (but still not too heavy)

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot of the *StExBar* (top-line toolbar)</sup>

Price and license match your requirements as well ☺

Answer (score 2):

I believe you shouldn't be looking for a clipboard manager that does this but a 3rd party program that does.  I don't know if there will be just a 3rd party program that solely does this though.  For example, I know that [Directory Opus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_Opus), a Windows file explorer alternative does this as one of its hundreds of functions.

**I Suggest AutoHotkey.** Personally, if I wanted to do what you want, it would take me about 15-30 minutes to write a script to do it.  I'd have to look at other scripts to remember the functions I would need and then quickly write a simple program.  So, if you like to tweak your computer in little ways such as creating:

1. hotkeys that will open any programs or websites,
2. hotkeys that will look up synonyms and google-search selections
3. toggle the hiding/showing of extensions or hidden files
4. scroll pages by pressing shifting plus the mouse wheel
5. and a hundred more simple things.

You can look into learning AutoHotkey.  I have been using it for about 4 months so far and I create simple scripts to do little things and it requires *minimal* resource usage.

**AutoHotkey Review.**  I'm going to give you a completely objective review of AutoHotkey.  It will appear really easy to learn and many will insist it is.  But, it'll take you *much* longer than you think.  Most things usually do, no?  Don't just think you can't learn it in a week.  It takes weeks and months to get a handle on it.  You'll keep forgetting how to do this and that.

Comment: Thanks, yes I was looking for a ready-to-use script :-) good to know that Directory Opus has this feature!